# Simplifying radicals in sympy

Tags: sympy

Although the [radsimp](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#radsimp) function looks like it's exactly what I want:

```
from sympy import radsimp, sqrt, symbols
v1, v2 = symbols('v1 v2')
radsimp(1 / (1 + sqrt(v1)))
  ____
╲╱ v₁  - 1
──────────
v₁ - 1
```

I can't get it to work with other simple fractions like this:

```
radsimp(sqrt(v1) / sqrt(v2))
  ____
╲╱ v₁ 
──────
  ____
╲╱ v₂
```

I need/expect it to do:

```
  ______
╲╱ v₁⋅v₂
────────
   v₂
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should probably report it on their [issues page](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues).

Comment: Done - thanks: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7408

Answer (score 3):

This works now

```
>>> radsimp(sqrt(x)/sqrt(y))
sqrt(x)*sqrt(y)/y
```